# BufferedWriter not flushing the data

Tags: java-io, bufferedwriter

here is a sample code from the application I am working on:

```
BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("abc.txt")));
StringBuilder sb = null;
ResultSet rs = pstmt.execute();
while(rs.next()){
  sb = new StringBuilder();
  createLine(rs,sb);
  bw.write(sb.toString());
}
bw.flush();
bw.close();

private void createLine(ResultSet rs, StringBuilder sb){
   //based on conditions append the columns to string builder
   sb.append(rs.getString("prodname"));
   // and goes on...
}
```

Now, when I execute this program, what I observed is that only 8kb of file got generated and the program hangs as if its waiting for something to be cleared. I know for sure that with the amount of data that get retrieved from the database a file of atleast 40-50kb should get generated.
Will putting flush statement inside the for loop solve the problem?

Comment: Done. createLine only appends columns from the resultset to the StringBuilber.

Answer (score -1):

> Will putting flush statement inside the for loop solve the problem?

No, it will just slow things down. You don't even need the single `flush()` call you already have, as it happens automatically when you `close().`

Your problem lies elsewhere.